# How do I use LDAP for moodle?

Tags: ldap, moodle

As there are no tutorials available on Internet. I want to add users & courses from moodle to LDAP database. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting to sync the users or authenticate against the LDAP server?

If you are looking to sync then you are better looking at Totara which is a distro of Moodle which is packaged with various extensions and tools, one of which is a very robust sync solution.

If you are looking to authenticate then there is an LDAP authentication plugin included with Moodle. If you go into Site administration / ▶︎ Plugins / ▶︎ Authentication / ▶︎ Manage authentication then you will be able to enable and configure the LDAP auth plugin.

Comment: Are there any tutorials available for sync of moodle and LDAP ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Moodle docs?

https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/LDAP_authentication

There are sections there on synchronising and on creating user accounts in Moodle based on LDAP

I don't think there is a way to add courses from Moodle to LDAP (ie exporting them from Moodle), only automatic enrolment/course creation in Moodle of courses that exist on LDAP/external database
https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/LDAP_enrolment